# How was the Dominated Convergence Theorem applied on this proof?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

> The DCT states that if  $f_n$ is a sequence of measurable functions and if there exist $g\in L$ such that $|f_n|\le g$ and $f_n\to f$ pointwise then $f\in L,$ $\lim\int|f_n-f|=0$ and $\lim\int f_n=\int f$

(Similar result to the $L^p$ version)

In this proof there is $|f-S_k(f)|^p\le2^{p+1}|g|^p.....(1)$

I think that is because we want something similar to $|f_n|\le g$.

In this case, $f_n=f-S_k(f)$?

On the other hand, $2^{p+1}$ should be in (1)?

How to remove to have only $|f-S_k(f)|^p\le |g|^p$ ?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I changed the name of the sequence in the statement of the DCT to $h_k$ to avoid confusion with the sequences in the proof.

Yes, you're correct, they are defining $h_k$ by $h_k(x)=f(x)-S_k(x)$ (if you're using the $L^p$ version of the dominated convergence theorem; otherwise, take the $p$'th power of the absolute value). This goes to $0$ pointwise a.e. As for the dominating function, the constant $2^{p+1}$ doesn't affect integrability, so it doesn't matter. If you want to write it exactly in the form of the DCT (the standard version, similar for the $L^p$ version), you can take the dominator to be $G(x)=2^{p+1}|g(x)|^p.$ Since this is integrable, the dominated convergence theorem tells us that $$\|h_k\|_{L^p}=\|f-f_{n_{k+1}}\|_{L^p}\rightarrow 0,$$ and so $f_{n_k}\rightarrow f$ in $L^p$. The result now follows from Cauchiness.

Comment: why $f_n(x)=f(x)-S_n(x)$ ? Why the difference converge to $f$ ?

Comment: It doesn't, it converges to zero. Note $f_n(x)=f(x)-f_{n_{K+1}}(x).$ You apply the dominated convergence theorem to show this converges to $0$ in $L^p.$

Comment: But the theorem requires $f_n\to f$ so one must have $f-S_K(f)\to f$

Comment: Here, $f_n(x)\rightarrow 0$ pointwise. We use dominated convergence to show that $\|f_n\|_{L^p}\rightarrow 0$, or equivalently that $\|f-f_{n_K}\|_{L^p}\rightarrow 0.$ The $f$ in the statement of the dominated convergence theorem will be $0$ here.

Comment: @galleta I changed notation to clarify. The notation in the DCT and the proof you put was too similar.

Comment: thanks I could understood this part. I thought this was going to be the difficult part but no! the difficult of the difficult is the last inequality of the proof.

Comment: I'm glad you understood! Have you figured the whole proof out?

Comment: nop, not yet. I am trying, i'll continue in this another week more and we'll see :3